# How can I get more information (apart from PID) of the sender process when a signal is received ? Like process name and it's args

Tags: linux, systemd, init, pid

I am running an Embedded Linux OS with systemd as init. Sometimes I see systemd manager does a log dump during early bootup upon receiving SIGUSR2 signal. I found the sender PID using `signalfd()` but by the time I try to print using `cat /proc/pid/cmdline` there seems to be no trace of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a small piece of code in `kill()` system call in `kernel/signal.c` to execute a script to get more details about the sender process (cmdline, its parent, etc.,)

**Code in kill() system call:**

```
 // We are concerned only about SIGUSR2 to init
 if (17 == sig && 1 == pid)
 {
     printk("PID %d sent SIGUSR2 to systemd\n", info.si_pid, pid);
     char *envp[] = { "HOME=/", NULL };
     char *argv[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "/etc/getSenderInfo.sh", NULL };
     call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
 }
```

**/etc/getSenderInfo.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=$(dmesg | grep -w "sent SIGUSR2 to systemd" | awk '{print $2}')

while [ $pid -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "ps -o ppid= -o cmd= -p $pid"
    ppid=$(ps -o ppid= -o cmd= -p $pid)
    echo $ppid
    pid=$(echo $ppid | awk '{print $1}')
done
```

I am not sure if this is the most right way but this did the trick for me